# What is a variable as opposed to a parameter?

Tags: definition

What is a variable as opposed to a parameter?

I have never seen or heard of a clean definition.

As of my opinion, a parameter is a fixed value, whereas a variable is, deep thought, the result of an undefined function, like it is for "stochastic" variables, minus that "stochastic" prefix.

Comment: The 2 answers so far are by example, not by definition (not even by  unsourced definition).

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical expressions involving many letters and other symbols are often used to define functions, such as
$$ax^2+bx+c.$$

Writing $n$ for the number of distinct letters involved (four in the example above), the domain of the function one has in mind is usually not as big as $\mathbb R^n$, but rather $\mathbb R^m$, where $m$ is the number of a chosen  subset of letters which are called the variables, while all others are called parameters.

Of course, in order to define a concrete function, the parameters must be assigned fixed values, with  different choices leading to different functions.

Speaking of the example above, a popular choice is to call $x$ the variable and $a$, $b$ and $c$ the parameters, but nothing prevents us from making other choices.

Answer (score 0):

A parameter is a constant that can be varied if desired. Variables depend on parameters that can be changed.

$$ (x,y)= (2ft,ft^2) $$

is a parabolic curve equation where any point can be associated with a parameter $t$. When $t$ is eliminated we have a single equation $ 4 f y=  x^2. $

Several parameters can be used to distinguish parabolas of different focal lengths $f$.

Comment: Still "I have never seen or heard of a clean definition."